# How to separate each column of matrix for every 100 numbers each time in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, calculated-columns

In MATLAB I have a matrix with of 80000*20 numbers. I would like to calculate the mean, maximum and minumum for the first 100 numbers in column 1 (0-100), the next (second) 100 numbers (101-200) in column 1, the third 100 numbers in column 1 (201-300), etc. Simular for all columns. I think I need sort of a loop to separate the matrix, because of the large deminsions of the matrix. How can I do this?

So for example: 
Matrix:

A1 A2 A3 A4 A5

B1 B2 B3 B4 B5

C1 C2 C3 C4 C5

D1 D2 D3 D4 D5

E1 E2 E3 E4 E5

F1 F2 F3 F4 F5

Then I would like the mean, minumun and maximum of A1 B1 C1 and mean, minimum and maximum of D1 E1 F1. Simular for column 2 (A2 B2 C2) and (D2 E2 F2),3,4,5,6..etc

regards,

Vincent

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just for future reference, it is customary to post some code indicating what you have already tried when you post a question here. If you could remember that for the future it would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: ps If you feel my response solves your problem, then please click the tick mark next to it to mark the question answered.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of two possible solutions. One uses a loop. The other converts your matrix into a cell array, performs the operations on the cell array using `cellfun`, and then converts the answer back to a matrix.

```
%# Build random matrix X
T = 12;
N = 3;
X = randi(100, T, N);

%# Set the number of elements in each mean, min, and max calculation
K = 4;

%# Determine the number of groups
L = T / K;
if mod(L, 1) ~= 0; error('Number of rows not integer divisible by number of elements per group'); end

%# Loop based solution
Soln1 = nan(L, N);
for k = 1:K-1
    Soln1(k, :) = mean(X(k * K - K + 1:k * K, :));
end

%# Loop-less solution
CellOfMat = mat2cell(X, K * ones(L, 1), N);
Soln2 = cellfun(@mean, CellOfMat, 'UniformOutput', 0);
Soln2 = cell2mat(Soln2);
```

I have done the solution for the `mean` function in the above example. The case of `max` and `min` follows trivially upon substitution of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative loop-less solution that doesn't use cells.

```
% M is the 80000x20 matrix
rows_per_dataset = 100;
rows_in_solution = size(M,1)/rows_per_dataset;

% flatten out the matrix so each column is one dataset
M_grouped = reshape(M,rows_per_dataset,rows_in_solution*size(M,2));
means = mean(M_grouped);
means = reshape(means,rows_in_solution,size(M,2));
% the value in each row and column is the mean of the corresponding dataset
% in the original data
```

For large enough data sets, however, copying the data to a temporary variable is inefficient, and a loop-based solution is better.

Comment: This is very useful, thanks for your help! But indeed, a loop-based solution might be better in case of a large matrix.